# Which episode of Fantastic Max is this picture from?

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification

Which episode of *Fantastic Max* is this picture from?

[image: fantastic max photo]

Comment: For any close-voters. Fantastic Max travels in space, and has various science-fiction themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from [Fantastic Max, Episode 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Max#Season_1_.281988.29); **"Journey to the Center of my Sister"**

> Zoe gets plagued with Nasal Bathrobe, the virus from Osirus, on the
>   day of her birthday party. By order of Agent Wally, Max and company
>   have to capture the virus or else they'll never go into outer space
>   again.

[image]